# animate div height based on other div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the div height of `.article_description` with jQuery uniquely for each occurrence of that div. I want it to be set so that:

```
$(".article_title").height() + $(".article_description").height() + $(".article_notes").height() = $(".photo_well").height().
```

I do not want to change the height of `.article_title`, `.article_notes` or `.photo_well`.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="article_well_main" >
    <div class="row" >

       <div class="photo_well col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12"> 
        <img src="<%=asset_path "#{article.image}", alt:''%>" style="width:100%">
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12" >

         <h4 class="article_title"></h4> 
         <p class="article_description"><%= article.description%></p> 

         <div class="row">

           <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
             <p class="article_location" style="font-size:10px"><%= article.date_published %>  &nbsp|&nbsp <%= link_to article.source, "http://www.#{article.source}", :target => "_blank"%> </p>
             </div>
             <div class ="article-notes col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
             <i><%=article.notes%></i>
             </div>

         </div>
       </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var photo_well_height = $(".photo_well").height();
var article_title_height = $(".article_title").height();
var article_notes_height = $(".article_notes").height();
var article_description_height = photo_well_height - article_title_height - article_notes_height;

$('.article_description').css(height: article_description_height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of:

```
$('.article_description').css({ height: article_description_height });
$('.article_description').css("height", article_description_height);
$('.article_description').height(article_description_height);
```

`.css(height: article_description_height);` is a syntax error.

Comment: none of those worked... .article_description disappeared for all of them.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(article_description_height);` and let me know the output?

Comment: I don't have anything set up to view console logs...I guess I probably should, unless there is a simple way to do it. I'm obviously new to JS.

Comment: Most modern browsers will have built-in developer tools (hit F12 if you are in Chrome). I definitely recommend using developer tools for problems like this. The logs will appear in the console tab.

Comment: okay...console says 206, so it is at least getting the proper height

Comment: Ok, after playing around with your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e61rv4j2/1/) (I replaced your template code with latin text and cleaned up some of the classes). I got it working. You reference `.article_notes` in the javascript, but in the HTML, the class name is `article-notes` (with a dash, not underscore). Changing that seemed to make it work.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but it is still not working. ".article_description" div appears empty.

Comment: Ok, there is probably something else happening. Are there any errors in the console? Can you load the page, view the source, and find the code with the actual content in it (not template code, `<%= ... %>`), then put that in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Is there any other javascript acting on these elements to your knowledge?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ngthudk0/ There are no errors in the console. Only other JS I have is endless scrolling with will_paginate.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me:

```
$(".article_description").load(function(){
    $(this).css({height: article_description_height});
});
```

However, it is using the first "article_description_height" for all of them. I want a unique article_description_height for each ".article_description" div.